# Virtual Machine Trouble

Tags: windows-95

I have an old Windows 95 CD and I unzipped its contents. I have all of the files on a flash drive and copied into my virtual machine's hard drive. It won't boot!

Please help me!

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to use a [DOS boot disk or CD](http://www.bootdisk.com/bootdisk.htm) with DOS CD-ROM drivers to boot the virtual machine, then run setup from the Windows 95 CD. You can just mount the boot floppy/CD image in a virtual floppy/CD drive in the VM, and configure a separate virtual CD drive for the Win95 install CD. In your case, configure the second virtual drive access your host machine's CD-ROM drive since you're trying to install from physical media and not an image.

Answer (score 3):

As Rob said, you will need a Dos Boot disk.

An alternative is that if this is a bootable Windows disk, simply mount the disk as the virtual cd drive and attempt to boot from it/install like normal.

Answer (score 2):

It does not boot because:

1) Filesystem is probably not FAT16

2) Boot sector does not contain anchor code for IO.SYS

3) Reference to IO.SYS is not located in the first sector of root 
directory

I.e. you need to boot from DOS boot disk, make FDISK /MBR, FDISK and make sure C: is active, then SYS C: ; also make sure disk C: is FAT16 and starts at sector 63 (not 2^n, as modern FDISK would have create it).